# How do I move an entire forest tree to the left?

Tags: tikz-pgf, forest, trees, linguistics

I'm looking for a way to shift this entire tree to the left, so it can fit on the page with the wider spacing I'm looking for. The white space on the left is there whenever I have the arrow drawn.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand\Fut[1]{Fut}
\newcommand\Akt[1]{Akt}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{forest}
for tree={s sep*=5,%
             inner sep=0,%
             l=0}%
    [TP
        [NP$_x$, name=dx 
            [*ma, roof]
        ]
        [T'
            [T[tə \\ \Fut{}]]
            [AgrP
                [NP [*ma, roof]]
            [AspP   
                [AKT$_k$[∅ \\ \Akt{}$_{st}$ ]]
                [VP %[ɖa afal, roof]
                    [$t_x$, name=tx]
                    [V' [$t_k$]
                        [V'
                            [V
                                [ɖâ]
                            ]
                            [NP
                                [afal, roof]]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
%
\draw[->] ([xshift=-1mm]tx.south) ..controls +(-2, -3.25) and +(-3, -3).. ([yshift=0.5em]dx.south west);%
\end{forest}

\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please extend your code to a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: It looks like the extra space comes from the curve's bounding box, load the [`bbox` library](https://ctan.org/pkg/tikz-bbox) and use `bezier bounding box` as an option to the `\draw` command at the end there.

Comment: @Qrr Adding "bezier bounding box" as an option improves things a little but doesn't solve it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The TeXnical clean solution will be [@Qrrbrbirlbel's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/679628/how-do-i-move-an-entire-forest-tree-to-the-left#comment1686542_679628).

However in your particular case, you can also draw the arrow with the `overlay` option. This will make sure that the arrow does not influence the bounding box.

Technically the arrow now slightly goes into the margin, but I think the tree itself looks better if it is centred on the page and with the round shape of the arrow, it is not very obvious that it goes beyond the text.

```
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand\Fut[1]{Fut}
\newcommand\Akt[1]{Akt}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{forest}
for tree={s sep*=5,%
             inner sep=0,%
             l=0}%
    [TP
        [NP$_x$, name=dx 
            [*ma, roof]
        ]
        [T'
            [T[tə \\ \Fut{}]]
            [AgrP
                [NP [*ma, roof]]
            [AspP   
                [AKT$_k$[∅ \\ \Akt{}$_{st}$ ]]
                [VP %[ɖa afal, roof]
                    [$t_x$, name=tx]
                    [V' [$t_k$]
                        [V'
                            [V
                                [ɖâ]
                            ]
                            [NP
                                [afal, roof]]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
%
\draw[->,overlay] ([xshift=-1mm]tx.south) ..controls +(-2, -3.25) and +(-3, -3).. ([yshift=0.5em]dx.south west);%
\end{forest}

\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]